# Getting Error in UseMethod when trying to use separate() function in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

In Table A, there are `Sports_Played` by individuals and their `Home_City`. I would like to convert Table A into Table B. I have tried using `separate()` and `count()` but I keep getting a Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

```
Table A

Sport_Played    Home_City
 Basketball      Toronto
 Soccer          New York
 Soccer          Toronto
 Football        Berlin
 Basketball      Atlanta
 Football        Berlin
 Football        Tokyo
 Football        Tokyo
 Basketball      New York
 Soccer          New York

Table B 

Home_City     Basketball     Football     Soccer
Toronto           1              0           1
New York          1              0           2
Berlin            0              1           0
Tokyo             0              2           0
Atlanta           1              0           0
```

Comment: You could just try `t(table(df))` if `df` is your Table A data frame.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Then I had to apply the ```pivot_wider``` function to widen the data set. I appreciate your help!